# How to use a component inside NProgress template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, components, template-literals

I want to use [NProgress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nprogress) module and add custom component inside template in `next.js` app. Originally I can set custom NProgress template by using below code:

```
NProgress.configure({
  template: "<div class='....'>...</div>"
});
```

Instead I want to do something like that:

```
NProgress.configure({
  template: `<div class='....'>${<MyCustomComponent />}</div>`
});
```

My custom component (`<MyCustomComponent />`) is regular `React` component or for example `Material UI` component, eg. `<CircularProgress />`.

Using `<MyCustomComponent />` inside `template` property as has been shown above will output `[object Object]`.

I know I can disable default spinner by setting `showSpinner` to `false` and use custom `state` to display own component but maybe there is a better solution.